# Erro INVALID URL quando tento criar um WebSocket em NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, servidor, websocket

Quando eu tento criar um websocket em nodejs fica dando o erro INVALID URL e eu nao consigo resolver.

```
var config = require('./ext/config.js');     
var ServURL = {
    port: config['port'],
    path: '/slither'
};
const WebS = require('ws');                  

var wss;                                                                        
wss = new WebS({ port: ServURL['port'], path: ServURL['path'] }, function () {          
    console.log('[INFO]: Server started at 127.0.0.1 at port 444');             
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou utilizar a biblioteca socket.io com express? Achei ela bem simples, há bastante informações na documentação o que facilita a integração:
[documentação do socket.io](https://socket.io/)

O servidor socket exemplo: socket.js, depois node socket.js está tá no ar.

```
const port =  process.env.PORT || 21001; //porta padrão
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
const socketio = require('socket.io'); 
var io = socketio(http, {perMessageDeflate: false});
http.listen(port, () => {
    console.info(`Servidor socket inicializado usando express na porta ${port}`);
});

io.set('transports', ['websocket']);
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.info(`Client entrou [id=${socket.id}]`);

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.info(`Client saiu [id=${socket.id}]`);
    });
    socket.on("mensagem-enviada", dados => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('mensagem-repassada', dados);
        console.log(`Localização recebida e repassada: ${JSON.stringify(dados)}`)
    });
});
```

Já no lado do cliente, pode-se usar assim:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io('http://localhost:21001', {transports: ['websocket']});
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log("socket conseguiu conecta");
    }); 
socket.on('mensagem-repassada', data => {
      console.log("localização recebida que foi repassada:");
      console.log(data);
    });

    function enviarMensagem(dados){
        socket.emit("mensagem-enviada", dados);
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Parece ser mesmo uma boa opção, mas o meu projeto e um mod e não posso trocar de library, se eu pudesse eu provavelmente usaria socket.io

Comment: [Link] https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#new-websocketserveroptions-callback
Você deveria instanciar o new WebSocket.Server({options...}, () => { console.log("seu callback"); } )

Comment: Como faço isso?

Comment: Rafael, tenta entender pouco mais a documentação do websockets, existe o lado do cliente e lado servidor. Eu não consegui entender o suficiente para conseguir explicar. 
Você tem que subir o serviço (servidor) de websockets e outra parte é o cliente que se comunicará com um servidor websocket.